# Aborted an update, is my server fine?

Tags: linux, ssh, update

First off let me say I'm new to linux servers. A few minutes ago I tried to update linux, but during the process it asked me if I wanted to start the update, it also said the update could take several hours. I decided to update later and so I typed "N". I was expecting it to return to my normal but instead it said something like "Command terminated with exit status 1". I did ctr + A + D but I'm wondering if I possibly broke something by aborting the update. Apologies for my horrible terminology, like I said, I'm new. :)

Comment: Did you copy/paste anything so we can have an idea of what you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

You're fine - that question is put in specifically to let you abort an update without damaging anything. You didn't so much "abort" the update as that you declined to continue after seeing the time it would take. This is a fairly uniform feature throughout most linux distribution update utilities.